# Google Cloud Vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION - always one page?

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I have been trying a variety of images (mainly via https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop, but also via the API), from pictures of several hand written pages laid out on a table, to an image of a rendered multi-page PDF, to pictures of books, and it seems like it always returns a single "page" (response format is `TextAnnotation > Page > Block > Paragraph > Word > Symbol`). The documentation is pretty thin on what the meaning of a "page" is, mostly just states the obvious. Could someone with experience clear this up, please?

Comment: @KJ you need to upload your own file (try anything with text, but preferably multiple pages), and then select "text"

Comment: You're clearly not understanding my question.